# IndexError: list index out of range error message only when using SSH

Tags: python, arrays, arraylist, ssh, raspberry-pi

My Raspberry PI is connected to a ds18b20 sensor, and I have a Python script which initiates the sensor and records the room temperature and saves it to a text file every 2 mins:

```
21.000
21.125
21.125
21.062
21.125
21.062
21.187
```

I have another Python script which reads the latest temperature from `temp.txt` and submits the value to MYSQL:

```
// selected_node.py
# Read current temp from txt file
with open('temp.txt', 'r') as f:
  lines = f.read().splitlines()
  last_line = lines[-1]
print last_line

...
```

When I run the Python script, everything works:

```
21.187
(1, 'record inserted.')
```

However, why is it that when I try to run the same script from a different Raspberry PI using `ssh -p 22 -i pi.rsa pi@192.168.1.xx python /home/pi/selected_node.py` I get the following error message:

```
File "/home/pi/selected_node.py", line 15, in <module>
last_line = lines[-1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: That means your `lines` array is empty, so you cannot get an index out of it, you need to check if the `temp.txt` you are reading is actually created and has some data in it

Comment: I am just curious, you are running the script from /home/pi/selected_node.py but the error says the file path as /home/pi/FYP/selected_node.py. Are you sure you have your temp.txt updated in the correct folder?

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh my `temp.txt' file has data in it, I'm able to run 'selected_node.py' script from the raspberry pi that it is on, I only get the error message when I ssh from another PI and execute the same script from the second PI

Comment: @SainathMotlakunta sorry forgot to update that line, but yes the file path is correct

Comment: Try using quotes in the remote command something like this ssh -p 22 -i pi.rsa pi@192.168.1.xx 'python /home/pi/selected_node.py'

Comment: @SainathMotlakunta Unfortunately that didn't work either, I'm still getting the same error message on PI2. I also made sure the files have the correct privileges so I can't think of what else it could be

Comment: What does `print(lines)` output for ssh?